# Typescript generics in react: SyntaxError missing semicolon

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this dummy code:

```
function f<T>() {}

type TEST<T> = typeof f<T>
```

which should be ok in typescript syntax (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFQHwAoCUiDeAvgFDFQCeADgKaJoCiAymuhogLyIU1zDKvEgA)).

However in my React project I get an error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: index.tsx: Missing semicolon.
```

The error is here:

```
type TEST<T> = typeof f<T>
                       ^
```

Playground: [Error](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-ubhsq9?file=/src/index.tsx)

What is possibly happening? Is that babel fault?

I expect `TEST` to be the type `() => void` for any `T`.

Comment: Did you try adding the semicolon?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, the expression `typeof something<generic>` cannot be broken by a semicolon...

Comment: I would guess this is an edge case where the parser cannot distinguish between a JSX tag and a type param and went with JSX tag. Try changing to `typeof f<T,>` (note the trailing comma). That will disambiguate it as a generic instead of markup.

Comment: Unfortunately same error plus `Trailing comma not allowed.ts(1009)` trying with `type TEST<T> = typeof f<T,>`

Comment: what version of TS are you using?

Comment: ts version 4.9.5
react version 18.2.0

Comment: Are you 100% sure?  I don't see the TS version written anywhere in your codesandbox project; as far as I can tell codesandbox.io is still using TS4.5, and instantiation expressions weren't released until TS4.7.

Comment: Yes sorry I wrote the ts version of my true project, I didn't check codesandbox one, now I've updated codesandbox one as well to 4.9.5 (the error still shows)

Comment: What I've found out so far (following the idea of @JaredSmith about parser confusion of `<>` in JSX) that if I move that type definition in a `.ts` file instead of `.tsx` and then I import it in the `.tsx` it runs successfully, so there is indeed a parser mismatch about the angle brackets meaning

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware, the TS version in codesandbox's editor is not user configurable, see https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/942.  It uses 4.5 and that's it, no matter what version you make the project depend on.  Ideally you'd demonstrate this with an editor where you can actually control the TS version.  For example, [this is the TS playground using TS4.6](https://tsplay.dev/Wyqy2W) and you can see that semicolon error.  Unless you can demonstrate the issue actually occurs for TS4.9.5, I'm skeptical that we've got a [mre] here.

Comment: Okey I didn't know that, so I'm trying to find a playground with a controllable typescript version to show the example but so far I couldn't find any, can you recommend one? However please see https://ibb.co/phJPLs0 for my current project status (check ts version, check code, check error)

Comment: I believe you (or at least I'm *willing* to believe you), I just can't easily demonstrate it for myself so I don't know how to help other than to give vague/general advice like the answer below.